# Google Earth Engine band did not match any bands errord

Tags: google-earth-engine, band, precipitation

According to the [dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_GFS0P25), there should be a band named: *total_precipitation_surface*. However, when I try to get data from this band I get:

```
> Collection.first: Error in map(ID=2019061000F000): Image.select:
> Pattern 'total_precipitation_surface' did not match any bands.
```

I works perfectly with other bands in this dataset, but for some reason it does not work for the band I want.

My code is:

```
var fc2 = ee.Geometry.Point([-159.5469188,21.9080489]);

Map.centerObject(fc2,10); //the last numbe is zoom level

print (fc2)

var data_collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GFS0P25');
var dataset = data_collection.filterBounds(fc2)
                    .filterDate('2019-06-10', '2019-06-15')
                    .select('total_precipitation_surface');


// Create a graph of the time-series.
var graph = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: dataset, 
  regions: fc2, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  //seriesProperty:'uniqe_name'
})
print(graph)
```

Comment: The short answer is not all of the images contain that band. Some have 6 bands, some have 9. Just trying to work out the filter syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hidden, but the dataset properties indicate that the `total_precipitation_surface` band is only available for those images where `forecast_hours > 0`. So, you can add in that metadata filter to select only those images.

```
var dataset = data_collection.filterBounds(fc2)
              .filterDate('2019-06-10', '2019-06-15')
              .filterMetadata('forecast_hours', 'greater_than', 0)
              .select('total_precipitation_surface');
```

Comment: Thanks, I now get an error -Error generating chart: Computation timed out, but I guess it has something to do with my account or internet connection, and not your answer. I actually don't understand why I get this error because I ask for one parameter for a short period of time.